# PHP: can't increase maximum upload limit

Tags: apache-2.2, upload, php

I'm using Apache + PHP 5.3.3-7 on Debian Squeeze, installed from the repositories. The PHP distribution in Debian Squeeze includes Suhosin patch. I have problems uploading files bigger than cca 4 MB, some invisible limit prevents the PHP from accepting the upload.

In `php.ini` I have:

1. set upload_max_filesize = 50M
2. set post_max_size = 50M
3. set memory_limit = 256M
4. set max_execution_time = 120
5. set max_input_time = 120

In `suhosin.ini`:

1. suhosin.memory_limit = 256M
2. suhosin.post.max_value_length = 50000000
3. suhosin.request.max_value_length = 50000000
4. suhosin.post.max_vars = 200000
5. suhosin.request.max_vars = 200000

I actually doubt the last two ones are important at all, but I was adviced to increase them as well.

I know for sure that PHP actually loads the config values correctly, since `phpinfo()` matches my expectations. I'm expecting to be able to upload a file up to 50MB, but uploading of 4MB already fails. There are no logged errors in normal PHP per-site logs. And I'm sure there is enough space is available to save the uploaded file.

It seems like there is some other invisible limit preventing me from uploading the files. What could this be? Perhaps the Apache itself? Never heard of this limit though.

I spent nearly one week on this and I'm desperate, as well as my customer. Any hints are welcome.

Comment: If you've really set `upload_max_filesize = 5OM`, the letter O instead of the number 0 may cause problems.

Comment: Thanks but was really just a typo, it's not present in the config file, i double-checked it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it seems that this is wrong.  Assuming a typo, but will point out anyway:

```
set upload_max_filesize = 5OM
```

That should be a `0` right?

```
set upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

It also seems like `memory_limit` is empty in your post as well?

Anyway, past those settings you should also adjust `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` so the upload itself does not timeout. Depends on speed and connection, but getting a proper grip on all of the above should allow you to upload 50MB files without too much issue.

Comment: Sorry for the typos, I edited the original post. The o->zero typeo is not present in the config file, double-checked it right now. Speaking of max_execution time and max_input_time, do they actually matter? My experience is that they are only meant to limit the time to parse the input (2 minutes for 50M should be more than enough) and to limit the execution of the script itself (excluding system calls, waiting for the input, etc, etc..). Waiting for slow upload from client doesn't count into the limit.

Comment: Hmmm… Okay, your settings look correct. But are these from your `php.ini` file? Or from running `phpinfo()` in PHP? Are you sure you edited the correct file?  And restarted Apache? And verified these settings in PHP via `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Yes, phpinfo() reflects my changes. And yes, I restarted Apache, even tried restarting the virtual server. I have an idea though. Could it be caused by a defective or misconfigured APC? The app I'm running requires APC and I needed to compile it from source, because the old version in repositories didn't include some features the script needed.

Comment: APC is a PITA. I would look into adjusting `/etc/php5/conf.d/apc.ini` via the config options outlined here: http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php

Comment: I tried to make a simple upload form and disabled the APC. Now everything works just fine. So now I know at least where the problems came from and I will investigate the APC issue further. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You’re welcome!  Also, check your APC version. The ones typically installed via a package installer are out of date compared to what you can get via PECL directly.  So I would recommend doing a force upgrade of APC that way so you are at least at the most stable version you can get. Also, check your main Apache error log (/var/log/apache2/error.log) for “Segmentation Fault” errors triggered by APC conflicts/flubs. Good luck!